# Handling additional column from JpaRepository

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I wrote my own query which returns all fields from the mapped class + column from case, only now he does not save this information from the case because he does not find such a field in the entity. 
So I created a field with the same name and added Transient annotations so that during mapping it did not add this column to the database, but it still cannot serialize the answer and add it to the field.

JpaRepository

```
@Repository
public interface EventRepository extends JpaRepository<Event, Long> {

    @Query(value="select partners.*,(CASE WHEN partners.partner_id =:user_id THEN true ELSE false END) as userExists from (select * from sms_events e left join sms_events_partner ep on (e.id = ep.event_id) where e.experience > current_timestamp) as partners ", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Event> getEventsBeforeExp(@Param("user_id") Long user_id);

}
```

Event Entity

```
@Entity
public class Event {

    @Id
    private long id;
    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
    @ManyToMany
    private Set<User> partner;
    private String type;
    private String description;
    private int availability;
    @NotNull
    private double latitude;
    @NotNull
    private double longitude;
    @NotNull
    private Date creationDate;
    private Date experience;
    private boolean status;
    @Transient
    private boolean userExists;
...
}
```

Comment: You could try Hibernate's `@Formula` annotation on the entity field.

Comment: @AlanHay can u suggest how should it looks like?